# MySQL / DRBD / Pacemaker on EC2

Tags: mysql, replication, linux, aws

I am trying to setup DRBD/MySQL/Corosync/Pacemaker on AWS EC2 instances, though I am not sure if it will work since how to integrate VIP is a problem for me.

Anyone have any thoughts on what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

For amazon AWS you have two options:

1. [Secondary Private IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html)
2. [Elastic IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

Then you'll need to edit your `IP2addr` resource agent (under `/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/IPaddr2`) to manage the IP failover in-front of amazon.

- For Elastic IPs [I found this solution](https://gist.github.com/therobot/5270626).
- For secondary IPs I guess you'll just need to include the AWS CLI
  commands: `ec2-assign-private-ip-addresses` when promoting and
  `ec2-unassign-private-addresses` when demoting.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using ucarp for VIP management in conjunction with DRBD

I have some posts advocating MySQL, DRBD and ucarp

- `Feb 10, 2014` : [MySQL High Availability for InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58594/mysql-high-availability-for-innodb/58606#58606)
- `Oct 17, 2012` : [Creating High Availability Cluster with PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27121/creating-high-availability-cluster-with-postgresql/27123#27123)
- `Dec 19, 2011` : [Best way to setup master to multi master replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/best-way-to-setup-master-to-multi-master-replication/9425#9425)

What might interest you the most is my old post [PostgreSQL Failover - What tools should I use?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14201/postgresql-failover-what-tools-should-i-use/14215#14215) where I actually have some sample code for setting up PostgreSQL with DRBD and ucarp. You can use the same setup for MySQL in the cloud or on bare metal machines.